# Positioning Button Android UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I´m banging my head with something stupid (at least I think so).

I need to place the red button at the far right of the screen. Right now I´m using a relative layout but it does not go all the way to the right.

Suggestions? :)

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can we see your (full) layout XML? Looks like there is padding on a parent element or it is getting clipped. Hard to tell without XML though.

Comment: Oh... unbelievable there was padding at the parent. Thanks @DariusHoule

Comment: For reference, this wast at the parent >android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

value in parent of button in your code

it makes the parent to add "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" gap between the right most end of the parent and it's children

remove that line & check whether the display is ok for you...